# How to fix sqlite insert last EditText value multi-time in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to insert 3 Edittext value in sqlite database in android
the insert function work well but it inset the last edittext value 3 time.
I insert (john, smith, anna) and sqlite insert (anna, anna, anna)
this is my code

```
LinearLayout ll;
EditText editText;
TextView textView;
String room;
Button save;

private DBHelper dbHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_room_name);

    final SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String room_number = (mSharedPreferences.getString("room_number", 
""));

    ll = findViewById(R.id.ll);

    final int num = Integer.valueOf(room_number);

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setHint("Room " + (i + 1) + " Name");

        textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10);

        ll.addView(editText);
        ll.addView(textView);

    }
    save = new Button(this);
    save.setText("save");

    ll.addView(save);

    save.setOnClickListener(v ->{

        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++){
            if(dbHelper.insertRoom(editText.getText().toString())){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using in the loop that you do the insert operation the same EditText, the last one of the 3 that you create programatically. 
Instead of:

```
EditText editText;
```

use an array to store the 3 EditTexts:

```
EditText[] editText;
```

and change the code to this:

```
LinearLayout ll;
EditText[] editText;
TextView textView;
String room;
Button save;

private DBHelper dbHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_room_name);
    final SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences =
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String room_number = (mSharedPreferences.getString("room_number",
            ""));

    ll = findViewById(R.id.ll);

    final int num = Integer.valueOf(room_number);

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

    editText = new EditText[num]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        editText[i] = new EditText(this);
        editText[i].setHint("Room " + (i + 1) + " Name");

        textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10);

        ll.addView(editText[i]);
        ll.addView(textView);

    }
    save = new Button(this);
    save.setText("save");

    ll.addView(save);

    save.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            if (dbHelper.insertRoom(editText[j].getText().toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: I edited. Added `editText = new EditText[num];` before the 1st loop.

Answer (score 0):

your approach is not correct . You should use Tag for each EditText and get each EditText by it's Tag.

```
LinearLayout ll;
  EditText editText;
   TextView textView;
   String room;
    Button save;

      private DBHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_room_name);

     final SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        String room_number = (mSharedPreferences.getString("room_number", 
           ""));

      ll = findViewById(R.id.ll);

      final int num = Integer.valueOf(room_number);

          dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

           for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setHint("Room " + (i + 1) + " Name");

        //set tag for edit text

       editText.setTag(i);




    textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10);


    ll.addView(editText);
    ll.addView(textView);

}
save = new Button(this);
save.setText("save");

ll.addView(save);

save.setOnClickListener(v ->{

    for (int j = 0; j < num; j++){
        if(dbHelper.insertRoom(editText.findViewWithTag(j).getText().toString())){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done", 
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

});

 }
```

Comment: error in this line : if(dbHelper.insertRoom(editText.findViewWithTag(j).getText().toString()))